# How to store username in a session variable in marklogic sjs

Tags: authentication, marklogic, okta, marklogic-10

We have an application running on Marklogic Server side Javascript.

We want to store the username in a session variable throughout the logged in session. What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 1):

[`xdmp.setSessionField()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.setSessionField) sets the value of a named session field for the session.

```
xdmp.setSessionField("user", "udhayha-karthik");
```

You can use the [`xdmp.getSessionFieldNames()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.getSessionFieldNames) function to return the names of the fields in the session and the [`xdmp.getSessionField()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.getSessionField) function to return a value set in a session field.

Comment: I tried this. But the variable seems to be blank when access from the next page. Are we supposed to do xdmp.login() before using this method?

Comment: Same appserver port and same user, and within session timeout? I've tested set and get with different requests both via /v1/eval REST calls and Query Console and am able to set various fields and retrieve them after in subsequent calls (but Query Console requests won't see REST fields and vice versa)